# HTML 5 input type email check validation on lost focus

Tags: html, validation, input, onblur

how can i check validation on lost focus of input type email of HTML5?

```
<input type="email" name="useremail" onblur="setCustomValidity('Plz enter email ')" />
```

Comment: It is `onblur`, not `onblure`.

Comment: did you miss the closing tag <input />

Comment: @bažmegakapa : it is typing mistake.. just ignore it or you have to just edit my question... :( that is not my question

Comment: @FaddelHomsi : this not required now.... i have edited

Comment: @Ankur How should I know if it's a typing question or the reason why your whole code is not working? Honestly. And what's that `setCustomValidity()` function? Could you paste that as well?

Comment: `typing mistake`, not `typing question` :).

Answer (score 0):

onchange event should do the trick.

Edit: You probably only want to validate when the value changes and field loses focus, that's why IMO the onchange event would be more appropriate than onblur (not onblure).

Reference: stackoverflow.com/a/785106/440519

Comment: <input type="email" name="useremail" onchange="setCustomValidity('Plz enter email ')"/>

Comment: @Javi both of them gave the same result, onblur and onchange